# SharePoint 2010: Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

I am new to SharePoint. I was hoping you can point me to the right direction to start with.

Here is what I have and am trying to do:

- I have one top level site and many sub-sites.
- A top level site and all sub-sites have a list called "Account"
- I want to add a new **Import from Excel** Robbon button to the **Account List\List Tools\Items\New** for all sub-sites and not for the top level site
- When user clicks on the newly added button, I want to display a dialog window which can allow users to browse an excel file on their computer

What would be the best and easiest way for me to add the ribbon button along with the import form to all sub-sites only for the Account list?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a different content type for the lists in the subsite, one derived from the top level content type. This way you can easily create a ribbon button and assign it to the new content type only